# Marshalling of a c++ struct which contains pointers to another c++ struct

Tags: c#, pointers, marshalling

I have an issue concerning the correct marshalling of c++ structs into c#. These are defined as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
    //Geometry forms that could be used for envelope calculation
    enum GeometryForms  {RECTANGLE, TRIANGLE, ELLIPSE, CIRCLESECTOR};

    //Structure for coordinates 3D
    typedef struct Coordinates
    {
        double  longitude;      //longitude of the point in dezimal deg
        double  latitude;       //latitude of the point in dezimal deg
        double  altitude;       //heigth of the point in metres
    } Coordinates, *PCoordinates;


    //Envelope Data Struct
    typedef struct EnvelopeStruct
    {
        GeometryForms   GeometryAft;        // Geometry form of the aft section
        GeometryForms   GeometryBow;        // Geometry form of the bow section
        GeometryForms   GeometryCurve;      // Geometry form during direction change
        GeometryForms   Geometry3DAboveWL;  // Geometry form 3D under the water level
        GeometryForms   Geometry3DUnderWL;  // Geometry form 3D above the water level
        Coordinates     *PointsAft;         // Coordinates of the part of the envelope of the aft section
        Coordinates     *PointsBow;         // Coordinates of the part of the envelope of the bow section
        Coordinates     *PointsCurve;       // Coordinates of the envelope during direction change
        Coordinates     *Points3DAboveWL;   // Coordinates of the envelope above water level
        Coordinates     *Points3DUnderWL;   // Coordinates of the envelope under water level
    }EnvelopeStruct, *PEnvelopeStruct;


    //Structure includes all parameters that are used for the envelope calculation
    typedef struct CalculationParametersStruct
    {
        double  pos_long;           //Position of the vessel, longitude in decimal degree
        double  pos_lat;            //Position of the vessel, latitude in decimal degree
        double  pos_alt;            //Position of the vessel, altitude in metres
        double  pos_long_future;    //Predicted longitude of the vessel in decimal degree
        double  pos_lat_future;     //Predicted latitude of the vessel in decimal degree
        double  pos_alt_future;     //Predicted altitude of the vessel in metres
        float   pos_future_time;    //Time or timeinterval between actual position and predicted position
        double  sigma_long;         //Accuracy of actual longitude
        double  sigma_lat;          //Accuracy of actual latitude
        double  sigma_alt;          //Accuracy of actual altitude
        double  PL_long;            //Integrity value (protection level) into longitude
        double  PL_lat;             //Integrity value (protection level) into latitude
        double  length;             //length of the vessel in metres
        double  beam;               //beam of the vessel in metres
        double  draft;              //draft of the vessel in metres
        double  max_t;              //maximum trim
        double  v;                  //velocity of the vessel
        double  course;             //vessels heading
        double  rate;               //Rate of Turn of the vessel
        double  angle;              //Rudder Angle of the vessel
        double  coef;               //Maneuvering Coefficient
        double  scale;              //Dangerous Cargo Scale
        double  scale_lon;          
        double  scale_lat;
        double  wave_lon;
        double  wave_lat;
        double  ENC_reliability;            
    }CalculationParametersStruct, *PCalculationParametersStruct;
```

I tried to accomplish with the subsequent code in c#, but it does not work for now:

```
public enum GeometryForms { RECTANGLE, TRIANGLE, ELLIPSE, CIRCLESECTOR };

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class Coordinates
    {
        public double longitude;        //longitude of the point in decimal deg
        public double latitude;     //latitude of the point in decimal deg
        public double altitude;     //height of the point in metres
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class EnvelopeStruct
    {
        public GeometryForms GeometryAft;       // Geometry form of the aft section
        public GeometryForms GeometryBow;       // Geometry form of the bow section
        public GeometryForms GeometryCurve;     // Geometry form during direction change
        public GeometryForms Geometry3DAboveWL; // Geometry form 3D under the water level
        public GeometryForms Geometry3DUnderWL; // Geometry form 3D above the water level
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 96)]
        public Coordinates PointsAft;           // Coordinates of the part of the envelope of the aft section
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 96)]
        public Coordinates PointsBow;           // Coordinates of the part of the envelope of the bow section
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 4320)]
        public Coordinates PointsCurve;     // Coordinates of the envelope during direction change
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 96)]
        public Coordinates Points3DAboveWL; // Coordinates of the envelope above water level
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 96)]
        public Coordinates Points3DUnderWL; // Coordinates of the envelope under water level
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CalculationParametersStruct
    {
        public double pos_long;         //Position of the vessel, longitude in decimal degree
        public double pos_lat;          //Position of the vessel, latitude in decimal degree
        public double pos_alt;          //Position of the vessel, altitude in metres
        public double pos_long_future;  //Predicted longitude of the vessel in decimal degree
        public double pos_lat_future;       //Predicted latitude of the vessel in decimal degree
        public double pos_alt_future;       //Predicted altitude of the vessel in metres
        public float pos_future_time;   //Time or timeinterval between actual position and predicted position
        public double sigma_long;           //Accuracy of actual longitude
        public double sigma_lat;            //Accuracy of actual latitude
        public double sigma_alt;            //Accuracy of actual altitude
        public double PL_long;          //Integrity value (protection level) into longitude
        public double PL_lat;               //Integrity value (protection level) into latitude
        public double length;               //length of the vessel in metres
        public double beam;             //beam of the vessel in metres
        public double draft;                //draft of the vessel in metres
        public double max_t;                //maximum trim
        public double v;                    //velocity of the vessel
        public double course;               //vessels heading
        public double rate;             //Rate of Turn of the vessel
        public double angle;                //Rudder Angle of the vessel
        public double coef;             //Maneuvering Coefficient
        public double scale;                //Dangerous Cargo Scale
        public double scale_lon;
        public double scale_lat;
        public double wave_lon;
        public double wave_lat;
        public double ENC_reliability;
    }
```

I get an **error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'EnvelopeCalculatorWrapper.Coordinates'** when I try to access

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 96)]
            public Coordinates PointsAft;
```

as an array in c# in the manner:

```
calc.envelope.PointsAft[i].longitude
```

Does anybody know how to do it!

Thanks in advance!

Cheers, Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare it as an array.  Add a constructor to initialize them:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class EnvelopeStruct {
        public EnvelopeStruct() {
            this.PointsAft = new Coordinates[4];
            // etc..
        }
        public Coordinates[] PointsAft;
        // etc..
    }
```

Don't use any attributes, the default marshaling is good as-is.

Comment: There still seems to be some error as values are not marshalled from c++ (values are set correctly) to c# (values are null) - I get a **NullReferenceException**. But your answer was helpful anyway, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that I need some `[In, Out]` attribute or `ref` keyword for the reason of my pevious comment?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use UnmanagedType.LPStruct, see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/23/56635.aspx).

**EDIT**
If you have a fixed size array embedded in the structure you should follow [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Quickly you should declare that field as array and specify it's a UnmanagedType.ByValArray. You have to specify the size too.

If, in the structure, you just have a pointer to the first element of the array you do not need any custom marshaling, default behavior is right (as posted by @Hans Passant)

Comment: Now, I marked it like this: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public Coordinates PointsAft;`. But it does not work, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Declare them as array too so you can access PointsAft with []

Comment: You mean like `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] public Coordinates[] PointsAft;`? Do I have to specify size of array, e.g., `SizeConst=100` or is there any way of doing it dynamically?

Comment: I'm sorry, for your case that's the wrong UnmanagedType, I corrected my answer.

Comment: No possibility to acccomplish this task in a dynamical way?

Comment: How is the synchronization (marshalling) between unmanaged and managed data indeed triggered? Just to understand how things are functioning ...

Comment: No, I mean when I call `calc.envelope.PointsAft[i].longitude` in C# I get a **NullReferenceException**, i.e., all `PointsAft` elements are `null`, although in C++ struct counterpart, the values are set, ergo, I thought I have to call some `Marshall()` to be able to access values in C# either!?

Comment: Sorry, do you have no more ideas or is my problem not explained in an understandable way?

Comment: Did you use LPArray or standard marshaling?

Comment: I did not use any attributes just as described above by Hans Passant.

Comment: Then try to use UnmanagedType.ByValArray with the size. Does it work?

Comment: No, it does not. If I check the types now, PointsAft, e.g., is an object[5] am no Coordinates[5] and its elements are all **?** (question mark) instead of **null**!?

Comment: No more ideas, I guess you tried all wrote all around here. In theory it should work...hmmmm...